# How cron log to multiple directories?

Tags: cron, logs, output

I want crontab script output to multiple directories. Also i want cron log to /var/ directory, I think it is requires sudo, how to make cron script log output to directory with sudo?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are asking. Are you trying to log *any* cron output to multiple log files, or are you asking how a script *run from* cron can output to multiple log files? Also, what is your system logger? Because in the first case that matters for the answer.

Comment: I have script running by cron. This script logs. I mean this logs

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'tee' for doing this

Example:

```
0 10 * * * user /path/to/myscript.sh | tee -a /path/to/file1 /var/path/to/file2
```

The output of myscript.sh is piped to 'tee' which appends the output to both files.

Make sure you have write permissions on the files you want to write.

If you have an internal log logic, you need to post your code of your script.